# How to Run ros2 launch file using service file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to run launch file in ros2 using service file but I am unable to do it.

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
Description=desc

[Service]
Environment=source home/$USER/dev_ws/install/setup.bash
ExecStart=ros2 launch topics topic.launch.py
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2s

[Install]
WantedBy=user.target
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: source
Feb 09 09:59:54 USER-pc systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/name.service:6: Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: home/USER/dev_ws/install/setup.bash
Feb 09 09:59:54 USER-pc systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/name.service:7: Executable "ros2" not found in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Can anyone please helpme

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371425/how-to-run-ros2-launch-file-using-service-file/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2021-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to resolve this issue by sourcing and running the launch file by using /bin/bash -c

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash; source home/$USER/dev_ws/install/setup.bash; ros2 launch pkg_name launch_file_name.launch.py; sleep 60'
```

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2021-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26642/robopo/) on 2021-11-23**:
Hi there, why do you have sleep 60? How is this important? Some sort of protection?

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-11-23**:
not that necessary, just gave it 60 sec before it starts again. If you have any other processes that need to close before you restart this might be a good option.